# How to align image with two text lines using Material UI

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I want to create a banner area with an icon on the left. In the middle is two lines (title and sub-title) with text. However, all three of these are showing up on separate lines.

You can see the problem here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-brook-71ucup?file=/src/App.js:366-402. For the sake of simplicity, I have replaced the area where an icon should appear with text.

```
import { Grid, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} direction="row">
          <Stack xs={3}>
            <Typography>Icon</Typography>
          </Stack>
          <Stack
            sx={{
              borderBottom: 1,
              borderColor: "grey.500",
              alignItems: "center",
              xs: 9,
              direction: "column"
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h5">My-Title</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h7" sx={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>
              My-Subtitle
            </Typography>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have trouble with Material UI because I don't know when to use Grid, Box or Stack and what properties apply to them. What is most puzzling to me is that even specifying the columns for each item isn't working. Any help on how I can debug these kinds of problems will also be most appreciated.

**Update:** I solved it by changing the <Grid item ...> to be a container as well <Grid item container ...>. The direction property is honored by the container, thereby allowing me to lay out the stacks side by side. The updated solution is in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically need is only the stack and along with the stack, you have to use Alert to create a Banner with Material UI.
Let me give you an example code:

```
<Stack sx={{ width: '100% }} spacing={2} >
  <Alert 
      severity="info" 
      sx={{ 
        fontSize: '14px'
        }}
    >
    "Title and Subtitle will be here"
  </Alert>
</Stack>
```

[Banner with a Todo addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbtSK.png)

First of all, you have to read about the grid what basically **gird** is:

Grid is a two-dimensional flow that has a row and column structure, you can use a grid when you want to specify your cards or give them specific rows and columns.

**Box** is just like a one-dimensional system where you have only one dimension and you want to specify your cards in one direction either row or column.
It is just like a normal CSS Flexbox and Grid system.

**Stack** is used for banners as you know.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Where should the icon go in your proposed suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the container attribute in addition to the item attribute to the grid. My problem was that the two stacks within the  were laid out vertically and the direction attribute set to "row" was ignored. When added the attribute container , the direction attribute was honored. I also did away with the use of xs attributes on the stack.

```
import { Grid, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid
          item
          container
          xs={12}
          direction="row"
          sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "grey.500" }}
        >
          <Stack sx={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Typography>Icon</Typography>
          </Stack>
          <Stack
            sx={{
              alignItems: "center",
              direction: "column",
              flexGrow: 1
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h5">My-Title</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h7" sx={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>
              My-Subtitle
            </Typography>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```